# postorder traversal plain javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, tree-traversal, postorder

I want to ask for help in a task where I have to walk through a tree and get it as a result:

```
 [ 4, 2, 5, 7, 6, 3, 1 ]
```

The class:

```
class Traversal {
  postOrderTraversal(tree) {
    // ...code here
  }
}
```

My object :

```
const tree = {
  value: 1,
  children: [
    {
      value: 2,
      children: [
        { 
          value: 4,
          children: [] 
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      children: [
        {
          value: 5,
          children: [],
        },
        {
          value: 6,
          children: [
            {
              value: 7,
              children: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Example illustration (we have a maximum of two children in each node):

```
                          +----------------+
                          |     value:   1 |
                          +----------------+
                            /            \
                           /              \
            +----------------+        +----------------+
            |     value:   2 |        |     value:   3 |
            +----------------+        +----------------+
               /                         /           \
              /                         /             \
 +----------------+       +----------------+       +----------------+
 |     value:   4 |       |     value:   5 |       |     value:   6 |
 +----------------+       +----------------+       +----------------+
                                                        /
                                                       /
                                         +----------------+
                                         |     value:   7 |
                                         +----------------+
```

If anyone can help with this, please use plain javascript so I can better understand it.

Comment: is `Traversal` a standard JavaScript class? I don't see it. This looks like there's a missing definition for Traversal here; can you include that?

Comment: is it possible for a node to have more than two children?

Comment: If your question is about how to represent the tree in a `Traversal` object, you should include that question first, before attempting to run an algorithm on the Traversal tree class. We need more information to help you :) good luck!

Comment: Mulan - possible but not required for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using recursion is nice to demonstrate how post order is working. I found this to be a relatively straightforward solution.

```
class Traversal {
    postOrderTraversal(tree, arr=[]) {
        if(tree) {
            this.postOrderTraversal(tree.children[0], arr);
            this.postOrderTraversal(tree.children[1], arr);
            arr.push(tree.value);
        }

        return arr;
    }
}
```

Since your data set is that of a tree, I assume that `children[0]` is considered to be the left node, and `children[1]` is considered to be the right node.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the easiest implementation I can come up with. Given just two lines of code, there's very little room for explanation -

```js
function *postorder(t) {
  for (child of t.children) yield *postorder(child)
  yield t.value
}

const mytree = {value:1,children:[{value:2,children:[{value:4,children:[]}]},{value:3,children:[{value:5,children:[]},{value:6,children:[{value:7,children:[]}]}]}]}

console.log(Array.from(postorder(mytree)))
```

```js
[4,2,5,7,6,3,1]
```

Confounding traversal with classes, though possible, serves no benefit to you. `postorder` remains unchanged -

```js
function *postorder(t) {
  for (child of t.children) yield *postorder(child)
  yield t.value
}

class Traversal {
  postorder(t) { return Array.from(postorder(t)) }
}

const mytree = {value:1,children:[{value:2,children:[{value:4,children:[]}]},{value:3,children:[{value:5,children:[]},{value:6,children:[{value:7,children:[]}]}]}]}

const q = new Traversal()

console.log(q.postorder(mytree))
```

Compare with `preorder`. The only change necessary to achieve this traversal is to switch the order of the two lines -

```js
function *preorder(t) {
  yield t.value
  for (child of t.children) yield *preorder(child)
}

const mytree = {value:1,children:[{value:2,children:[{value:4,children:[]}]},{value:3,children:[{value:5,children:[]},{value:6,children:[{value:7,children:[]}]}]}]}

console.log(Array.from(preorder(mytree)))
```

```js
[1,2,4,3,5,6,7]
```

Comment: But postorder isn't on the Traversal class ;) (being pedantic here)

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case with these sorts of tree-visiting algorithms, your best bet lies with recursion: Each node in the tree should return its own value, after the values of its children. There are certainly shorter and more efficient ways to do this than what I have written below, but I have structured the code in such a way that it is clear when the recursion terminates (the current node has no children) and in which order the values are added to the returned array for ease of understanding.

```
function postOrderTraversal(node) {
  if (node.children.length === 0) {
    return [node.value];
  } else {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      var childValues = postOrderTraversal(node.children[i]);
      arr = arr.concat(childValues);
    }
    arr.push(node.value);
    return arr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, I'm grateful.